# I want to sort string column with Prisma not use $queryRaw

Tags: mysql, sorting, prisma

I use MySQL.

A column called `AGE` contains numbers in the form of a string.

If I use prisma to sort, it's not 1-2-...-9

1-11-2-333-...-88-9 Sort like this.

I would like to know if there is any way to sort other than using $queryRaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model will look something like:

```js
model Person {
  id Int @id
  name String
  age Int
}
```

The type definition Prisma generates for the `orderBy` field is:

```js
export type PersonOrderByWithRelationInput = {
  id?: SortOrder
  name?: SortOrder
  age?: SortOrder
}
```

…and `SortOrder` is defined as:

```js
export const SortOrder: {
  asc: 'asc',
  desc: 'desc'
};

export type SortOrder = (typeof SortOrder)[keyof typeof SortOrder]
```

Unfortunately this means it is not possible to get `orderBy` to do what you want here.

Your options here are:

- use `queryRaw`,
- sort the array returned by Prisma in JavaScript / TypeScript,
- [use a materialized view](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/advanced-database-tasks/sql-views-postgres).